# Existence of symplectomorphism that preserves submanifolds

Tags: symplectic-geometry

I have the following question:

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold and let $N_1$ and $N_2$ be submanifolds of $M$ such that there is a diffeomorphism $\psi:M \rightarrow M$ such that $\psi(N_1) = N_2$. Does there exist a symplectomorphism $\varphi:M \rightarrow M$ such that $\varphi(N_1) = N_2$?

Can anyone give me a hint? I'm really struggling. Thanks!

Comment: What if one is a symplectic submanifold and the other is not?

Comment: Hmm, could you maybe give a specific example of such a case?

Answer (score 4):

As the simplest example I can think of, take a loop in $S^2$. There's a diffeomorphism taking any two loops to another; but the area of the two sides of the loop are preserved by a symplectomorphism (because symplectomorphisms are in particular volume-preserving).

More in line with my comment above, consider $T^*M$ with the standard form. The zero section is a Lagrangian submanifold, and you can easily check that a section (considered as a 1-form $\omega$) is Lagrangian if and only if $\omega$ is closed. But all sections are smoothly isotopic, whence there is a diffeomorphism taking one to another.

Comment: I don't get it. What is a 'loop' in S^2? Could you maybe give definitions or constructions? I'm not good with mental images of mathematical subjects I'm not familiar with. Also what do you mean by a section being Lagrangian? Sorry if these questions are stupid..

Comment: @user353840 An embedding of $S^1$ into $S^2$. For instance, any of the latitude curves. A submanifold of a symplectic manifold is Lagrangian if the pullback of the symplectic form vanishes identically on it.

Comment: So sections are submanifolds?

Comment: Their images are. If you don't understand that part of the answer, don't worry about it.

Comment: Oh ok. How exactly does that work? If $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ is a vector bundle and $s:M \rightarrow E$ is a section, then $s: M \rightarrow s(M) \subseteq E$ is a bijection. Do when then equip $s(M)$ with the quotient topology or?

Comment: subspace topology.